# Bluetooth Unknow Connection Error Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on a application where I am connecting to a device with Bluetooth which works good with all the android version but had some issues with Samsung galaxy tab 2 10.1.
**Problem:--**
If device turn offs after some time my application detects and then start searching for remote device. But application not able to find device (When turned on). I also have a normal device list activity when I again start normal searching here it founds device and also connects to it properly.
**Code:--** 
My connection code is as follow and I am using low level connection not serial porting.
Steps I follows:
1) Find bluetooth device (get mac)
2) Start HHDService.start();
3) HHDService.connect(Bluetooth device);

Main issue is Application not able to find device once device is disconnected...

```
public class HHDService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "HHDService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    boolean isRequestSend = true;

    // Unique UUID for this application
    //private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket = null;
    private InputStream mmInStream = null;
    private OutputStream mmOutStream = null;

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private Handler mHandler;
    //private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    private long waitTime = 15000;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming
                                                // connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing
                                                    // connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote
                                                    // device

    public static final int STATE_SLEEP = 4; // now connected to a remote
    // device

    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler
     *            A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public HHDBapiBTService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * 
     * @param state
     *            An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    public synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalValues.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1)
                .sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state.
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel(true);
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * 
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * 
     * @param socket
     *            The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device
     *            The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket,
            BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * 
     * @param out
     *            The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        if(getState() == STATE_SLEEP){
            connectionLost();
            return;
        }
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
                return;
            r = mConnectedThread;

        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
                return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        r.cancel();
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        if(getState() != STATE_LISTEN){
            setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        }

    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        //setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        setState(STATE_SLEEP);

    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection with a
     * device. It runs straight through; the connection either succeeds or
     * fails.
     */

    /* private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

            public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
                mmDevice = device;
                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

                // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
                // given BluetoothDevice
                try {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
                }
                mmSocket = tmp;
            }

            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
                setName("ConnectThread");

                // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
                mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    mmSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    connectionFailed();
                    // Close the socket
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                    }
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    HHDService.this.start();
                    return;
                }

                // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
                synchronized (HHDService.this) {
                    mConnectThread = null;
                }

                // Start the connected thread
                connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
                }
            }

    }*/

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        protected boolean simpleComm(Integer port) {
            // byte [] inputBytes = null;

            // The documents tell us to cancel the discovery process.
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            Log.d(this.toString(), "Port = " + port);
            try {
                Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                        new Class[] { int.class });
                mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, port);

                // debug check to ensure socket was set.
                assert (mmSocket != null) : "Socket is Null";

                mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                // attempt to connect to device
                mmSocket.connect();
                try {
                    Log.d(this.toString(),
                            "************ CONNECTION SUCCEES! *************");

                    // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
                    synchronized (HHDService.this) {
                        mConnectThread = null;
                    }

                    connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
                    return true;
                } finally {
                    // close the socket and we are done.
                    // //mmSocket.close();
                }
                // IOExcecption is thrown if connect fails.
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(this.toString(), "IOException " + ex.getMessage());
                if (port == 256) {
                    connectionFailed();
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                        mmSocket = null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                Log.e(this.toString(),
                        "NoSuchMethodException " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Log.e(this.toString(),
                        "IllegalAccessException " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Log.e(this.toString(),
                        "InvocationTargetException " + ex.getMessage());
            }catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                Log.e(this.toString(),
                        "NullPointerException " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (Integer port = 1; port <= 256; port++) {
                if (simpleComm(Integer.valueOf(port)))
                    break;
            }

        }

        public void cancel() {
             if (mmSocket != null) { 
                 try { 
                     mmSocket.close(); mmSocket = null;
                 } catch (IOException e) { 
                     Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect secure socket failed", e); 
                 } 
             }
        }

        public void cancel(boolean val) {
             if (mmSocket != null) { 
                 try { 
                     mmSocket.close(); mmSocket = null;
                 } catch (IOException e) { 
                     Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect secure socket failed", e); 
                 } 
             }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device. It handles all
     * incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

        private Logger logger;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            logger = Logger.getInstance();

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            byte commandByte = 00;

            //Logic to parse incoming data

        }; 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research found solution on it?? just add delay of (500 ms in my case) before requesting to open socket.

Comment: where to add the delay ??

Comment: @RajuGujarati - before socket.connect();

Comment: it still fails for my case . I have used Bluetooth Chat module to connect the device between the micro controller and the Android tablets. There is no response after sending the command to the micro controller.